# Update rules on Drools

Tags: drools

I am building a system where rules are updated very frequently.

By default the rules will be saved in a database. When

As far I understand, drools makes a sort of a tree when session is created.

1. Is it possible to update an existing rule without re-creating the session?
2. If I update the rule, will drools do a sort of re-indexing?

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question on Drools QA forum. Here is the answer I got from Toshiya Kobayashi.

```
Hi @Ankush Choubey

Is it possible to update an existing rule without re-creating the session?
Yes, KieScanner works for that. Please refer to this section.

https://docs.drools.org/7.71.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_kiescanner

If I update the rule, will drools do a sort of re-indexing?
What do you mean by "re-indexing"? Underlying KieBase is updated with the change.
```

https://kie.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/232677-drools/topic/Updating.20existing.20rules.20in.20Drools/near/285909960